# How to put default seconds value to jQuery datetimepicker by xdan?

Tags: jquery, datetime, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jQuery DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) by xdan. I can do what I desired, except the control over `seconds`.

[image: jQuery DateTimePicker by xdan]

The plugin itself isn't maintaining `seconds`. But the data I'm handling, that seconds precision is also important. So what we do, we choose `23:00` on the plugin modal, and it enters `23:00:##` and those hash (#) is the current PC value for seconds. We then manually change the value to `23:59:59`.

I could change the `59 minutes` by adding `defaultTime:'23:59:59'`. But this parameter is **not** adding the seconds value.

How can I force the plugin to add `:59` to the seconds value by default?